# Websocket broken but still receive ping message

Tags: node.js, ws

I'm using nodejs ws module to implement websockets. The socket is broken but I continue to receive ping messages. I've configured heartbeat function to auto-close and restart when broken, but because the ping message keeps coming the socket restart is not triggering.

Any reason why ping message continues to be received despite the socket being broken ?

Comment: Could you show your code? What do you mean by "the socket is broken"?

Comment: A bit of confusion here, I fear. When you use ws to communicate with a browser, the server must originate ping messages. Browser websocket support has no way to originate pings. When you use it for server-to-server communication either side can originate the ping. But if the ping arrives, *the connection is not broken.* Please [edit] your question to give more details about your setup, and show some code.

Comment: This is happening in Nodejs server-server communication. The reason I say the connection is broken is because the "message" event stops firing and only the "ping" is received. I've never seen such a scenario, so just wanted to be sure if there is something that I missed.